# how to move to matching end of a code block?

Tags: vi

In a c code, where code blocks are delimited by {..}, I can use "%" to move to the end of the block.

But in other languages (eg system-verilog), which uses features like:

```
class a;
   ...
   if(x)
     ....
   endif
endclass: a // here the ":a" is optional
```

how can I move from the first line of a block to its matching end line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Vim, there is an extension called `matchit.vim` in `macros` directory in the Vim folder, or you can download latest version of it at vim.org. You can configure it yourself if it doesn't support your choice of language out-of-the-box.

Link to the plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39

Comment: I found that the matchit.vim already exists under the macros directory. And as per the instructions, I did:
:let b:match_words = 'if:endif'
and then hit '%' on a 'if'. Cursor did not move. I also tried:
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
Same result. I am using vim 7.4 on windows.

Comment: Ah, indeed it is already in macros since Vim 6.0. Try `:source \path\to\matchit.vim`, does it work now?

Comment: It works in unix. Does not work in the windows version. The windows version is the default one I had downloaded from vim.org

Comment: That is strange, I just tested and it works for me in gVim in Windows.

Comment: I just used the default `matchit.vim` which is in the macro directory. It works for me after sourcing it. You could also add `:source \path\to\matchit.vim` to your `.vimrc` to load it automatically.

Comment: I tried different combinations- just refuses to work in windows (and no error messages either). But it works inside cygwin, so I have a workaround for now. Thanks. (BTW, I deleted some of my earlier comments, because stackoverflow does not like more than 6 comments at a time.)